# Iterating over DS.hasMany in Ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a real struggle with Ember.

In my model I have an attribute:

`options: DS.hasMany('UserOptions', {async: false})`

In a view linked to this model I can easily access this property by e.g.:

```
{{#each options AS |option|}}
    something....
{{/each}}
```

and that works like a charm.

However when I try to access this model value in controller with:
`this.get('model.options')`
instead of getting a lovely array of payment options, I get an ember model array of objects, and there's no way I can access the actual data.

Do you guys have any idea how do I access this data in controller and process it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `this.get('model.options').toArray()` or relationship is treated as Promise, so `this.get('model.option').then((result)=> { let newArray = result.toArray()})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved my case:

```
@get('model.options').toArray().forEach((item) ->
  console.log(item.get('parameter_name')]
)
```

That's true that `console.log(@get('model'))` was throwing something strange in console, however when I asked for a specific parameter, it was there!

My problem was that I was trying to print out an entire object instead of a specific value. The values were there, it just didn't print the entire object for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

`this.get('model.options')` will give you `RSVP.Promise`, so you need to work with asynchronous code. Use:

```
this.get('model.options').then(options => {
    options.forEach(option => {
        // do what you need with option
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've tried that and unfortunately I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).then is not a function`... :/

Comment: Is model loaded when  you do that? What console.log(this.get('model')) gives you?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.

`console.log(this.get('model'))` prints out

    Class {id: "4868", store: Class, container: Container, _internalModel: InternalModel…}
    adapterError:null
    areChildrenDirty:ComputedProperty
    changeVersion:32
    container:Container
    currentState:(...)
    id:"4868"
    isError:false
    store:Class
    toString:function ()
    willDestroy:function willDestroy()
    _internalModel:InternalModel
    _oldWillDestroy:function superWrapper()
    _super:function superFunction()